# Why i cannot find a group of measures in calculation view in my cube structure SSAS

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, fact-table

I can't find this new group of measures in the calculation view even after i process the cube?

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to most other things shown in BIDS, which are the local state, the items shown in Calculation Tools/Meta Data on the Calculations tab of the cube editor are fetched from the cube running on the server where you deploy your cube. And they are only refreshed on demand.

To refresh these, you have to Re-Connect, by clicking on the third button (named reconnect) in the toolbar, or select the menu entry Cube/Reconnect.

Comment: I still have the samne result :(

Comment: @user3597231 Is the measure group invisible, or are all its measures invisible? And did you deploy the solution before processing?

Comment: in fact the mesures are visible, I change only the name of two mesures, i deploye the cube after that but nothing is happend. Maybe it has a relation with the fact that I use these mesures in other things like perspectives and actions? I really don't know why ? (the version of my sql server is : 2008R2) tnx

Comment: @NidalaS But after the deployment you re-connected as described in my answer?